# Does a computer system need both cache memory as well as virtual memory, or can one replace the other? Why or why not?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

I know that Cache memory increases the accessing speed of CPU. Whenever the program is ready to be executed, it is fetched from main memory and then copied to the cache memory. But, if its copy is already present in the cache memory then the program is directly executed. However, the Virtual Memory increases the capacity of main memory. In virtual memory, even such programs which have a larger size than the main memory are allowed to be executed. I still don't know if it need both for a computer system.

Comment: Virtual memory and cache memory are two totally different things, it's not a "one or the other" relationship. Virtual memory is an abstraction to solve a bunch of problems with exposing physical addresses to applications while a cache is about avoiding repeated, expensive trips to main memory. "However, the Virtual Memory increases the capacity of main memory" -- no, virtual memory is just the OS hiding physical addresses to create the illusion that every process has access to the whole address space. Virtual memory doesn't actually increase physical capacity.

Comment: *However, the Virtual Memory increases the capacity of main memory.* - Paging does that, and is enabled by virtual memory.  But more importantly, virtual memory gives each process its own virtual address space.  Completely unrelated to what cache does.  Neither are needed for a computer system, e.g. OSes like DOS and Atari ST's TOS ran on systems without cache or an MMU.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, virtual memory and cache are different things, and they are not interchangeable.

Virtual Memory is an abstraction of the physical memory of a system--this allows sequential virtual memory addresses to be located in different locations in memory (and not necessarily sequential physical addresses). This also, on paper, appears to make the system have more memory than it actually has. For example, the memory space dedicated to each program is huge, and potentially larger than the amount of memory your computer has. However, virtual addresses allow for the OS to only use physical memory as needed, while still using the Virtual addresses space you'd expect (and hence how the stack can grow down, and the heap can grow up).

The cache on the other hand is part of the computer's memory higherarchy. Basically, all forms of storage have a speed vs size and cost tradeoff. The cache is the fastest to access, but there is very little of it (in comparison to the lower levels). Below the cache, you have your computer's ram. Its much slower to access, but you have much more of it. Eventually you work your way down to the disk/page file or even cloud storage. By treating each level of the higherarchy of the lower layers, the system is able to greatly increase access time.

So while both are not technically needed (some embedded systems will only use physical addresses), you would want both on your typically computer.

TL;DR: Virtual Memory is used by the OS to manage your physical memory, allowing the system to appear to have more memory to each program (but in reality, you still are limited to how much physical memory you have). The cache is used to help speed up the access to frequently used data by storing it in a faster to access medium.

Comment: On most systems, stacks grow downward, usually from near the top of virtual address space.  Either choice is possible on some ISAs, but growing down is baked in if you want to use efficient instructions like x86's `call` and `ret` for example, and for kernel code baked in by how hardware interrupts and exceptions use the stack.

Comment: But yeah, on most CPU designs, cache transparently makes *physical* RAM faster.  (Historically some CPUs have had virtually-addressed L1 caches that needed the OS to flush them on context switch, but most modern systems have physically tagged caches.)  Either way caches are orthogonal to virtual memory.  One would work without the other, and there's no overlap in their benefits.

Comment: Don't signal edits in the text with "edit:", especially not something that only needed to go in the edit changelog message.  Fixed that for you.